# How to write a shell script to start gedit and not showing the terminal window?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How to write a shell script to start gedit and not showing the terminal window?

That means: when I click the file `runme.sh`, only `gedit` window shows, no terminal window shows. Just like I click the `gedit`'s icon to start it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note, the solution proposed by @Wayne_Yux should work on Ubuntu. If you need a solution specific to Fedora, you'd have better luck on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) as this site focuses exclusively on Ubuntu

Comment: "Not work on Fedora 22 (GNOME) –  xmllmx 1 hour ago " You're on Fedora 22?

Answer (score 3):

save this as `run_gedit.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
gedit &
```

then run `chmod 755 run_gedit.sh` and you should be able to start it by clicking on the file.

Comment: Not work on Fedora 22 (GNOME)

Comment: mhm maybe you have to use it without the '&' or use `chmod 775` instead

Comment: I did as you said, and I click the file, nothing happened.